# I want to show a progress bar in mobile app showing the progress of the wear app's installation. Is there any way to track the installation progress?

Tags: android, installation, wear-os

I am new to Android Wear Development. I don't know the mechanism of the installation of Android Wear App. Ideally, in mobile side app, I am trying to set up a progress bar showing the installation progress of the wear app, because I want to give user some feedback during the installation, so that the user will know it is still running, not no response.

Is there anyway I can track the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to so this, however you really dont have to worry about your wear app being installed to the watch. It will be done automatically when the user installs your phone app.